# Is text-to-speech possible with Apple Watch WatchKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech, watchkit, apple-watch

Is Text-To-Speech possible in WatchKit? Basically, I want to play audio based on text on an Apple Watch. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted???? It is a simple yes or no question wether there's TTS on apple watch or not.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can now
derive you class from AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate, and add

```
import AVFoundation

var synth:AVSpeechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer.init()
synth.delegate = self
synth.speak(utterance)
```

Comment: THank you for that bit! That helped! Is it correct, that I can only use that function when the screen of the watch is on and the watchOS app is not in the background?

Comment: Jonathan, I am unsure. In my case I was text-to-speech a code number to user after his action so didn't try in background.  I guess apple would put some barrier there due to energy consumption

Comment: I tried for a day, didnt work in the background. so I created my own text-to-speech function for numbers between 1 and 220 (for speaking the heartrate bpm). if anyone is interested in how I did it, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't play audio directly from the Apple Watch's speaker.

Comment: I've read the documentation and there is no API. Also search on SO and you'll find many answers saying that it's not possible to play a sound directly from the device's speakers.

Comment: On watchKit you are not able to play audio through the watch but on WatchOS you are able to play back audio files and record. @BalestraPatrick

Comment: @lostAtSeaJoshua Isn't that only if you have a Bluetooth headset connected?

Comment: It uses the Apple Watch to play audio. The function is presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:options:completion:

Comment: I HAVE been able to playback audio from the speaker in the iWatch (WatchOS 2.1, iOS 9.2.1). If you need the code, open a question and tag me, I am around SO almost daily.

Comment: This answer may have been true when it was written, but now it is definitely possible. I've used apps that do it.